# Idris function to construct empty `List a` where `a` is bound to an instance of `Ord`?

Tags: typechecking, idris

I've only read the [standard tutorial](https://github.com/idris-lang/idris-tutorial) and fumbled around a bit, so I may be missing something simple.

If this isn't possible in Idris, please explain why. Furthermore, if can be done in another language please provide a code sample and explain what's different about that language's type system that makes it possible.

Here's my approach. Problems first arise in the third section.

#### Create an empty list of a known type

```
 v : List Nat
 v = []
```

This compiles and manifests in the REPL as `[] : List Nat`. Excellent.

#### Generalize to any provided type

```
 emptyList : (t : Type) -> List t
 emptyList t = []

 v' : List Nat
 v' = emptyList Nat
```

Unsurprisingly, this works and `v' == v`.

#### Constrain type to instances of `Ord` class

```
emptyListOfOrds : Ord t => (t : Type) -> List t
emptyListOfOrds t = []

v'' : List Nat
v'' = emptyListOfOrds Nat     -- !!! typecheck failure
```

The last line fails with this error:

```
When elaborating right hand side of v'':
Can't resolve type class Ord t
```

`Nat` is an instance of `Ord`, so what's the problem? I tried replacing the `Nat`s in `v''` with `Bool` (not an instance of `Ord`), but there was no change in the error.

#### Another angle...

Does making `Ord t` an explicit parameter satisfy the type checker? Apparently not, but even if it did requiring the caller to pass redundant information isn't ideal.

```
 emptyListOfOrds' : Ord t -> (t : Type) -> List t
 emptyListOfOrds' a b = []

 v''' : List Nat
 v''' = emptyListOfOrds (Ord Nat) Nat     -- !!! typecheck failure
```

The error is more elaborate this time:

```
 When elaborating right hand side of v''':
 When elaborating an application of function stackoverflow.emptyListOfOrds':
         Can't unify
                 Type
         with
                 Ord t

         Specifically:
                 Can't unify
                         Type
                 with
                         Ord t
```

I'm probably missing some key insights about how values are checked against type declarations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As other answers have explained, this is about how and where the variable `t` is bound. That is, when you write:

```
emptyListOfOrds : Ord t => (t : Type) -> List t
```

The elaborator will see that 't' is unbound at the point it is used in `Ord t` and so bind it implicitly:

```
emptyListOfOrds : {t : Type} -> Ord t => (t : Type) -> List t
```

So what you'd really like to say is something a bit like:

```
emptyListOfOrds : (t : Type) -> Ord t => List t
```

Which would bind the t before the type class constraint, and therefore it's in scope when `Ord t` appears. Unfortunately, this syntax isn't supported. I see no reason why this syntax shouldn't be supported but, currently, it isn't.

You can still implement what you want, but it's ugly, I'm afraid:

Since classes are first class, you can give them as ordinary arguments:

```
emptyListOfOrds : (t : type) -> Ord t -> List t
```

Then you can use the special syntax `%instance` to search for the default instance when you call `emptyListOfOrds`:

```
v'' = emptyListOfOrds Nat %instance
```

Of course, you don't really want to do this at every call site, so you can use a default implicit argument to invoke the search procedure for you:

```
emptyListOfOrds : (t : Type) -> {default %instance x : Ord t} -> List t
v'' = emptyListOfOrds Nat
```

The `default val x : T` syntax will fill in the implicit argument `x` with the default value `val` if no other value is explicitly given. Giving `%instance` as the default then is pretty much identical to what happens with class constraints, and actually we could probably change the implementation of the `Foo x =>` syntax to do exactly this... I think the only reason I didn't is that `default` arguments didn't exist yet when I implemented type classes at first.

Comment: thank you for detailed answer. Can you please comment on why Idris does not warn about shadowing type variables. Is it intentional?

Comment: Like many things, it's because it hasn't been implemented yet. It is probably only implicit shadowing of pi-bound variables that should be warned about though.

Comment: Why do you think explicit shadowing like in `f : (t : Type) -> (t : Type) -> List t` should not be warned? Is it useful somehow?

Comment: It's not impossible that a programmer would want to use the `t` twice explicitly, in between the bindings. People use shadowing for all sorts of reasons. I'd be happy to accept a patch that did either, really.

Answer (score 2):

You could write

```
emptyListOfOrds : Ord t => List t
emptyListOfOrds = []

v'' : List Nat
v'' = emptyListOfOrds
```

Or perhaps if you prefer

```
 v'' = emptyListOfOrds {t = Nat}
```

If you ask for the type of emptyListOfOrds the way you had written, you get

```
Ord t => (t2 : Type) -> List t2
```

Turing on `:set showimplicits` in the repl, and then asking again gives

```
{t : Type} -> Prelude.Classes.Ord t => (t2 : Type) -> Prelude.List.List t2
```

It seems specifying an `Ord t` constraint introduces an an implicit param `t`, and then your explicit param `t` gets assigned a new name.  You can always explicitly supply a value for that implicit param, e.g. `emptyListOfOrds {t = Nat} Nat`.  As far as if this is the "right" behavior or a limitation for some reason, perhaps you could open an issue about this on github?  Perhaps there's some conflict with explicit type params and typeclass constraints?  Normally typeclasses are for when you have things implicitly resolved... though I think I remember there being syntax for obtaining an explicit reference to a typeclass instance.

Comment: Yep, it seems strange that Idris allows variable overriding in types. E.g. `f : (t : Type) -> (t : Type) -> List t` is actually `f : Type -> (t1 : Type) -> List t1`.

Comment: I guess that stuff goes left-to-right. In the original question, at the point where `Ord a` is mentioned, `a` is undefined, and so introduced as an implicit param?  You can see that rule in action if you change the type param `a` to a capitol `A` - you'll get a `No such variable A` error.

Comment: Yep, it's left-to-right. `(t : Type)` actually is a [quantifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type#Formal_definition) so it always creates new variable. It is a bit unexpected that Idris does not even warn about capturing used variable.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just some thoughts.

The problem here is that `(t : Type)` introduces new scope that extends to the right but `Ord t` is outside of this scope:

```
*> :t emptyListOfOrds 
emptyListOfOrds : Ord t => (t2 : Type) -> List t2
```

You can add class constraint after introducing type variable:

```
emptyListOfOrds : (t : Type) -> Ord t -> List t
emptyListOfOrds t o = []
```

But now you need to specify class instance explicitly:

```
instance [natord] Ord Nat where
  compare x y = compare x y

v'' : List Nat
v'' = emptyListOfOrds Nat @{natord}
```

Maybe it is somehow possible to make `Ord t` argument implicit.

Comment: You can acquire the (unnamed) instance using `%instance`:

`v'' = emptyListOfOrds Nat %instance`